# How is a many to many self-relationship in data modeling represented in database tables and how is the query SQL instruction?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to query the player names according to their ID keys in their table from the two foreign keys in the match table of their self-relationship (as player plays with player).

I'm using MS Access, and the tables and fields are these:

### PLAYER

player_id (PK)

player_name

### MATCH

match_id (PK)

player_name_id (COMPOSITE FK from player_id)

opponent_name_id (COMPOSITE FK from player_id)

I added the match_id field only because it's important to have an id to identity the match, but the real identification is the combination of two different players, meaning a player mustn't play vs themselves, as it's each player vs everyone else.

There are players registered in the fields of both tables.

I'm not sure what the SQL instruction should be in order to bring the match_id along with the respective player names in the player_name_id and opponent_name_id fields in a query according to their foreign keys.

In order to establish the self-relationship in MS Access between the tables, the way I found was to open the same PLAYER table twice and establish the following relationships:

[self-relationship established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqSum.png)

As you can see above, the table PLAYER was mirror-opened as PLAYER_1. I had to establish the self-relationship this way because whenever I try to establish two relationships coming from player_id to two fields in the MATCH table as foreign keys, Access undoes one relationship when doing the second, so I'm also not completely sure this is correct. In the query, however, the two relationships are shown as they should as you can see below:

[self-relationship in the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8B1q.png)

After doing a lot of research for the SQL instruction, I found something called self-referencing, which seems to be the case here, but the ones I found were only used in a same table. But according to what I learned, it seems that I should address the MATCH table twice using two different aliases so that it brings the player name from the player_name_id differently than the opponent_name_id.

So I imagine the SQL instruction should look something like this:

`SELECT Match.Match_ID, p.Player_name, o.Player_name FROM Match p INNER JOIN Match o ON (Player.Player_ID = Match.Player_name_ID) AND (Match.Opponent_name_ID = Player.Player_ID);`

The results I got after much trial and error was that I'd either get the query right, except that instead of showing the player names as intended, I'd only see their ID numbers or I'd get only the rows of data which had players playing vs themselves, which shouldn't be allowed.

What I wanted in my query was a result like this:

[expected query table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOITQ.png)

Could someone tell me if I made the self-relationship in Access properly and what the right SQL instruction is for the result I'm seeking? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your question boil down to _SQL instruction should be in order to bring the match_id along with the respective player names_. Note that in your supplied sample query you don't reference the `player` table at all. You'd need to at least do that (twice) to get player names.

Comment: Did you try Access query designer? Pull in Player twice, one each joined to player_name_id and opponent_name_id in Match.

Comment: Hi Nick.McDermaid. Yes, you are right. I didn't get to use the JOIN with the Player table in that instruction example, but I don't know how to properly formulate the SQL instruction either. Could you tell me how it should be written? And yes, my question boils down to that as long as the relationships I established are correct.

Hi June7. I did that, but it brings me only one row, one that contains the same player ID number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a self Join and you can open the sql pane of the designer and write it if your sql skills are up to the task.  The trick is getting the designer to write it:

I set up the relationship properly with the relationships tool but when I opened the query designer I got:

[image]

Whatever your Query designer shows set up the query to dupe the players table by dragging the players table onto the design surface a second time and hooking the second table up like so:
[image]

```
'resulting sql
SELECT Matches.MatchID, Players.PlayerName, Matches.PlayerID, Matches.OpponentID, Players_1.PlayerName
FROM Players AS Players_1 INNER JOIN (Players INNER JOIN Matches ON Players.PlayerID = Matches.PlayerID) ON Players_1.PlayerID = Matches.OpponentID;
```

```
'output
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      MatchID       | Players.PlayerName |      PlayerID      |     OpponentID     | Players_1.PlayerNa |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | Marcos             |                  1 |                  5 | Daniel             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | John               |                  2 |                  4 | Carlos             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | Jane               |                  3 |                  6 | George             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | John               |                  2 |                  5 | Daniel             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 | Carlos             |                  4 |                  6 | George             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notes:There was no need for me to finish setting up the relationship for Players_1.  Also it is often easier to edit the sql than to adjust the designer for these types of queries but if the query is complicated beware.  Access rewrites the query when it switches between the designer and sql panes and it can screw up the translation when the query is complicated

Comment: Thank you very much, mazoula. That works. It just seems that from what I tried, MS Access can't execute the query on this self-relationship if you use the query design; it seems it fails to understand that both Match.PlayerID and Match.OpponentID come from the Player.PlayerID. It works only if you make the query via SQL.

Only one question: from the way Access related the tables, should the mirror table Player_1 relationship line with Match have referential integrity? I think it should, but MS Access shows two screens in which one shows having it and the other not having it.

Comment: for the first part try to build the query from scratch to as shown.  so in the query designer delete any relationships and put them back as shown.  Make sure to add or drag the players table twice so Access creates Players_1.  If that doesn't work try bug fixing by deleting any relationship with the relationship tool and repairing the database.  Next, since this is a select query specifying what to do on delete/update has no meaning.  You can set those relationship settings or not.